# How to emulate a click on a MapBox GL JS map?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I need to emulate a user click on my MapBox GL JS map.

I doesn't matter where in my map: could be useful to do in the point at the center of my maps if this could be easier.

## UPDATE

I've found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323105/programmatically-opening-a-popup-in-a-mapbox-map something that could be useful ...

```
map.fireEvent('click', {latlng: L.latLng(28.04419, -81.947864)});
```

... but seems to be something about Leaflet

I'd like my code coud be something like this ("broken code" ... )

```
    bounds = map.getBounds();
    x = bounds._ne.lng;
    y = bounds._ne.lat;

    map.fireEvent('click', {latlng: L.latLng(x, y)});
```

Does fireEvent exist in MapBox GL JS or are there alternatives?

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: You're right .. I've tried to add some more details and a "pseudo" code example ...

Comment: So you want to fire it using some other bit of client side code, rather than from some server-side action? https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#MapMouseEvent ?

Comment: Yes! Please, could your give me an example? Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the doc for [Map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map):

> The Map class mixes in Evented methods.

Doc for [Evented](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#evented) has info on [fire](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#evented.fire) so you can use something like `map.fire('click', { lngLat: ll, point: pt })`.

Comment: Note that `map.fire` is now deprecated as of v.0.45.0:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#%EF%B8%8F-breaking-changes-3

Answer (score 3):

Any answer that depends on `map.fire` [is deprecated](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#0450).

To simulate a click in MapboxGL, the easiest method involves using the `.click()` method in any element.

```js
document.querySelector('canvas').click()
```

This may not be what you're looking for; you might wish to click at a certain location. This is where [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) is your friend:

```js
const map = document.querySelector('canvas')

const event = new MouseEvent({
  clientX: 200,
  clientY: 200,
  bubbles: true
}

map.dispatchEvent(event)
```

*This may not work if you have more than one map or html canvas on the screen. If you find yourself selecting the wrong element with the query selector, add `id="map"` to your map html element, and use `document.querySelector('#map')` instead.*

Comment: I needed `new MouseEvent('click', {...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`map.fire('click', { latLng: coords, point: map.project(coords), originalEvent: {} })`

From: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5060