# MapBox GL JS + mapbox-gl-draw plugin: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm using MapBox GL JS and the mapbox-gl-draw plugin.

I need to show a little buffer around my clicked points during my edit session.

All seems working fine but I obtain a "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined*" in my browser console.

Here you are a little sample that show how to replicate the error ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
        }
    </style>
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v3.0.11/turf.min.js'></script>
    <script src="mapbox-gl-draw.js"></script>
    <link href='mapbox-gl-draw.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
 <body>
  <div id='map'></div>

  <script>
    var theCoords;

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGFuc3dpY2siLCJhIjoieUZiWmwtVSJ9.0cPQywdbPVmvHiHJ6NwdXA';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', //stylesheet location
        center: [9.10349459743145,39.20711996956351], // starting position
        zoom: 13 // starting zoom
    });

    var Draw = mapboxgl.Draw({
      displayControlsDefault: false,
      controls: {
        'point': true,
        'trash': true
      }
    });

    map.addControl(Draw);

    map.on('mousedown', function (e) {
      //alert("MouseDown!!");
      console.log("MouseDown!!")

      pixelCoords = e.point;
      geoCoords = e.lngLat;

      x = pixelCoords.x;
      y = pixelCoords.y;

      lng = Number(geoCoords.lng.toFixed(5));
      lat = Number(geoCoords.lat.toFixed(5));

     var feature = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [lat, lng] };

     currentPoint = {
       "type": "Feature",
       "properties": {},
       "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [Number(lng), Number(lat)]
       }
     };

     bufferCurrentPoint = turf.buffer(currentPoint, 100, 'meters');

     addBufferPointToMap(bufferCurrentPoint)
    });



    function addBufferPointToMap(bufferCurrentPoint) {
      try {
        map.removeSource("buffer");
        map.removeLayer("buffer");
      }
      catch(err) {
        console.log("The source and layer \"buffer\" are not defined");
      }

      map.addSource('buffer', {
          'type': 'geojson',
          'data': bufferCurrentPoint
      });

      map.addLayer({
             'id': 'buffer',
             'type': 'fill',
             'source': 'buffer',
             'layout': {},
             'paint': {
                 'fill-color': '#088',
                 'fill-opacity': 0.5
             }
      });
    }


  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you try to execute, starting the edit session clicking on the pinpoint at the hight left corner, then clicking on the map, you'll see something like this ...

[image]

Note that, instead, if you use this code ....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
        }
    </style>
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v3.0.11/turf.min.js'></script>
    <script src="mapbox-gl-draw.js"></script>
    <link href='mapbox-gl-draw.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
 <body>
  <div id='map'></div>

  <script>
    var theCoords;

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGFuc3dpY2siLCJhIjoieUZiWmwtVSJ9.0cPQywdbPVmvHiHJ6NwdXA';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', //stylesheet location
        center: [9.10349459743145,39.20711996956351], // starting position
        zoom: 13 // starting zoom
    });

/*
    var Draw = mapboxgl.Draw({
      displayControlsDefault: false,
      controls: {
        'point': true,
        'trash': true
      }
    });

    map.addControl(Draw);
*/
    map.on('mousedown', function (e) {
      //alert("MouseDown!!");
      console.log("MouseDown!!")

      pixelCoords = e.point;
      geoCoords = e.lngLat;

      x = pixelCoords.x;
      y = pixelCoords.y;

      lng = Number(geoCoords.lng.toFixed(5));
      lat = Number(geoCoords.lat.toFixed(5));

     var feature = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [lat, lng] };

     currentPoint = {
       "type": "Feature",
       "properties": {},
       "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [Number(lng), Number(lat)]
       }
     };

     bufferCurrentPoint = turf.buffer(currentPoint, 100, 'meters');

     addBufferPointToMap(bufferCurrentPoint)
    });



    function addBufferPointToMap(bufferCurrentPoint) {
      try {
        map.removeSource("buffer");
        map.removeLayer("buffer");
      }
      catch(err) {
        console.log("The source and layer \"buffer\" are not defined");
      }

      map.addSource('buffer', {
          'type': 'geojson',
          'data': bufferCurrentPoint
      });

      map.addLayer({
             'id': 'buffer',
             'type': 'fill',
             'source': 'buffer',
             'layout': {},
             'paint': {
                 'fill-color': '#088',
                 'fill-opacity': 0.5
             }
      });
    }


  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

... where I've commented the code portion where I load the mapbox-gl-draw plugin, and you try to click on the map, all works fine....

How may I avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an explanation as to why you're seeing that error when drawing tools are hooked up to the map. Maybe a bug with that version of mapbox-gl-js? If you switch to v0.22.0 the error goes away.

The error goes also goes away using 0.18.0 if you take a different approach:  re-use your source instead of removing and adding a new one on each click. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.18.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
        }
    </style>
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v3.0.11/turf.min.js'></script>
    <script src="mapbox-gl-js-draw/mapbox-gl-draw.js"></script>
    <link href='mapbox-gl-js-draw/mapbox-gl-draw.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
  <script>
    var theCoords;
    var bufferId = 'buffer';

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGFuc3dpY2siLCJhIjoieUZiWmwtVSJ9.0cPQywdbPVmvHiHJ6NwdXA';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map', // container id
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', //stylesheet location
      center: [9.10349459743145, 39.20711996956351], // starting position
      zoom: 13 // starting zoom
    });
    var draw = mapboxgl.Draw({
      displayControlsDefault: false,
      controls: {
        'point': true,
        'trash': true
      }
    });

    map.on('load', function() {
      // Add the source and layer, with some dummy data in the source.
      map.addSource(bufferId, {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': { type: 'Feature', geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [null, null] } }
      });
      map.addLayer({
        'id': bufferId,
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': bufferId,
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
          'fill-color': '#088',
          'fill-opacity': 0.5
        }
      });
    })
    map.addControl(draw);
    map.on('mousedown', function(e) {
      console.log("MouseDown!!")

      pixelCoords = e.point;
      geoCoords = e.lngLat;

      x = pixelCoords.x;
      y = pixelCoords.y;

      lng = Number(geoCoords.lng.toFixed(5));
      lat = Number(geoCoords.lat.toFixed(5));

      var feature = {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [lat, lng]
      };

      currentPoint = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [Number(lng), Number(lat)]
        }
      };

      bufferCurrentPoint = turf.buffer(currentPoint, 100, 'meters');
      var source = map.getSource(bufferId);
      source.setData(bufferCurrentPoint);
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried and works fine. I think that your solution is better than mine so I'll adopt and I'll update the mapbox-gl.js reference cdn ... Do you have also a sample for this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209411/how-to-emulate-a-click-on-a-mapbox-gl-js-map ?:-)